# How to get max of column based on grouping by date column in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

First time poster here, not sure if my title really outlines what I am looking for here...

I am trying to get the following:

"Which month of the year does each property type earn the most money on average?"

I have two tables with the following fields I am working with:

```
calendar_metric
    period (this is a date, formatted 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    revenue
    airbnb_property_id
property
    property_type
    airbnb_property_id
```

I have figured out how to get the month, property type, and average revenue to display, but am having trouble with grouping it correctly I think.

```
select
    extract(month from calendar_metric.period) as month,
    property.property_type,
    avg(calendar_metric.revenue) as average_revenue
from
    calendar_metric
inner join property on
    calendar_metric.airbnb_property_id = property.airbnb_property_id
group by
    month,
    property_type
```

What I want it to output would look like this:

```
month | property_type | max_average_revenue
---------------------------------------------
   1  |   place       | 123
   2  |   floor apt   | 535
   3  |   hostel      | 666
   4  |   b&b         | 363
   5  |   boat        | 777
   etc|   etc         | etc
```

but currently I am getting this:

```
month-property_type | max_average_revenue
---------------------------------------------
   1  |   place       | 123
   2  |   floor apt   | 535
   1  |   place       | 444
   4  |   b&b         | 363
   4  |   b&b         | 777
   etc|   etc         | etc
```

So essentially, months are coming back duplicated as I extracted the month from a date stamp, the data set goes across 5 years or so, and am probably not grouping right?  I know I am missing something simple probably, I just cannot seem to figure out how to do this correctly.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

you should be `grouping` by `year-month`, since you are trying to view `5 year` period.

```
select
    extract(month from calendar_metric.period) as month,
    property.property_type,
    avg(calendar_metric.revenue) as average_revenue
from
    calendar_metric
inner join property on
    calendar_metric.airbnb_property_id = property.airbnb_property_id
group by
    extract(year from period),
    month,
    property_type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is basically there, it's just returning all months rather than just filtering out the rows you don't want.  I'd tend to use the [`DISTINCT ON` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) for this sort of thing, something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (property_type)
  p.property_type, extract(month from cm.period) AS month,
  avg(cm.revenue) AS revenue
FROM calendar_metric AS cm
  JOIN property AS p USING (airbnb_property_id)
GROUP BY property_type, month
ORDER BY property_type, revenue DESC;
```

I've shortened your query down a bit, hope it still makes sense to you.

using CTEs you can express this in two steps which might be easier to follow what's going on:

```sql
WITH results AS (
  SELECT p.property_type, extract(month from cm.period) AS month,
    avg(cm.revenue) AS revenue
  FROM calendar_metric AS cm
    JOIN property AS p USING (airbnb_property_id)
  GROUP BY property_type, month
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (property_type)
  property_type, month, revenue
FROM results
ORDER BY property_type, revenue DESC;
```